# How can I make a UIButton get a function when I touch outside the button and drag over the button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

If I had a label and a button If i touch outside the button and swiped over the button then an event should be fired to display "hello" in the label field. tell me how can I do it?. Its not about touching the button. i can touch any part of the screen .I starts to swipe the mouse after touching any part of the screen, then if I swipes over the button ,it should call a function something like display a text in label.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Button's Touch Drag Enter method to do your stuff.

Comment: [UIControlEventTouchDragEnter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIControlEventTouchDragEnter)